# Java setSoTimeout Not Working on Windows

Tags: java, sockets, jvm

I am attempting to set a socket timeout on a Java application. Some of the developers are on OS X, others are on Windows. The issue is on Windows machines we get a SocketException: Connection reset after exactly 2 minutes, regardless of what the timeout is set to. However on OS X it works exactly as expected.

It seems like this is specifically an issue with how the JVM is interacting with the underlying Windows socket libraries. Is there anyway to address this issue.

Here is a snippet of code that creates the socket.

```
protected Socket openSocket() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    Socket socket = new Socket();
    SocketAddress endpoint = new InetSocketAddress( this.getHost(), this.getPort() );
    try {
      if ( this.getConnectTimeout() != null ) {
        socket.connect( endpoint, this.getConnectTimeout() );
      } else {
        socket.connect( endpoint );
      }
    } catch ( ConnectException ex ) {
      throw ex;
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
      ConnectException connEx = new ConnectException( 
          String.format( "Failed to connect to service at %s:%d. Reason: %s", 
              this.getHost(), this.getPort(), ex.getMessage() ) );
      connEx.initCause( ex );
      throw connEx; 
    }

    logger.debug( "Socket opened to {}:{}", this.getHost(), this.getPort() );

    if ( this.getResponseTimeout() != null ) {
      socket.setSoTimeout( this.getResponseTimeout() );
    }

    return socket;
  }
```

The code calling openSocket is then calling read on the socket returned.

Answer (score -1):

Read timeouts don't cause connection resets. They cause `SocketTimeoutExceptions` (in Java).

A connection reset is therefore not evidence that setting the read tiemout isn't working. It might be evidence of something else, for example a firewall rule.

Your conjecture is false.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was the following code in the calling method

```
StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
try (Socket socket = openSocket();
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream psOut = new PrintStream(os, true);
        BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));) {
  logger.trace("Opened socket");
  try {
    psOut.println(requestXML);
  } finally {
      socket.shutdownOutput();
  }
```

This caused FIN_WAIT to be sent, and it appears Windows kills sockets in that status automatically after two minutes. Then when the read occurred it caused a SocketException: Connection reset.

Comment: FIN_WAIT is not sent. FIN is sent. If you have some independent evidence that 'Windows kills sockets in that status automatically after two minutes' please provide it. If this was true `shutdown()` with SHUT_WR would be more or less useless.